# What is the motivation for clique-sum of graphs?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, soft-question, definition

It just feels strange to me that you insist the two graphs are glued on a clique but then make the clique disappear in the final definition?

What is the motivation behind this?

Comment: In the clique-sum I know, the clique is still there at the end. What is your definition of clique-sum?

Comment: Upon further research (that is, reading the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique-sum)), there are several definitions, each trying to solve its own problem, and some of them do delete some edges. Which definition are you using and for which application? Then we may be able to explain why it is that way.

Comment: @MishaLavrov  I'm going by the definition in  Demaine  and Hajiaghayi's paper    LINEARITY OF GRID MINORS IN TREEWIDTH
WITH APPLICATIONS THROUGH BIDIMENSIONALITY    where you require cliques pregluing but delete the cliques in the gluing process.

Comment: Oof, so you're trying to understand the clique-sums in the [graph structure theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_structure_theorem). I'll try to see if I can make sense of it, but it's kind of scary, so hopefully someone who's more of an expert will come along in the meantime.